# Hiding the Default form authentication url in asp.net mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-routing

I have an application which is configured to use

> ~/Account/LogOn

in the

> web.config

file for the authentication.

I would like to have the URL just point to www.example.com instead of www.example.com/Account/LogOn.

I have tried to have the routing configuration as follows, but it does not work

```
routes.MapRoute(
            "Default",                                              // Route name
            "{controller}/{action}/{id}",                           // URL with parameters
            new { controller = "Account", action = "LogOn", id = "" }
        );
```

Kindly suggest the right practice that can be used. I tried to remove the loginurl from web.config file but it is not of use and shows authorization error while running.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure you may change routing to have the same address for two actions: `Home/Index` and `Account/LogOn`. But if you want change default logOn routing you need 2 steps:

1) Add one more routing:

```
//This route returns www.example.com/Login
routes.MapRoute(
            "MyRoute",                                             
            "Login",                           
            new { controller = "Account", action = "LogOn", id = "" }
        );
```

2) Make changes in web.config:

```
~/Login
```

In the same way you may create any other routing for LogOn

As for me the only solution to have `login` on `Index` page is to do like this (and delete redirect from web.config):

```
@if(!Request.IsAuthenticated)
{
   //PartialView with Log In form
}
else
{
 // Your Index page content
}
```

Comment: I have even tried with a different controller (welcome) and it did not work

Comment: With the above route, I get the URL as www.example.com/account/logon?returnurl=login

Comment: @saravanan did you change web.config as in step 2? It seems you didn't

Comment: I have checked with a WelcomeController and the following web.config `<forms loginUrl="/Welcome" cookieless="UseCookies" name="FormAuthentication" />` and in `global.asax.cs` file, I have added as follows `routes.MapRoute("Default","Welcome",new { controller = "Account", action = "LogOn", id = "" });` and it works like `http://www.example.com/Welcome`.